# RabbitMQ localhost connection failed

Tags: go, rabbitmq, localhost, homebrew

I am trying to run a go file that needs connection to RabbitMQ and it gives error.

```
2021/05/23 14:16:32 Failed to connect to RabbitMQ: dial tcp: lookup localhost: no such host
exit status 1
```

I have rabbitMQ installed and started with `brew services start rabbitmq` command.

Also, I can't access `localhost:15672` page, I believe the UI management is enabled. When I install it, the terminal prints that the UI management is enabled by default. I have also tried the command `rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management` and got a response that says:

```
zsh: command not found: rabbitmq-plugins
```

Could anyone give me any idea to solve the connection problem? And what should I do to access localhost:15672?

I am using macOS big sure, go version go1.16.4 darwin/amd64

Comment: Correction: run with "brew services start rabbitmq" command

Answer (score 0):

It seems like RabbitMQ is not running. You can try starting it interactively by using the full path to the following command:

```
/usr/local/sbin/rabbitmq-server
```

Once the service is started, you should be able to open the management UI at http://localhost:15672.

You can manage plugins by using the full path to the `rabbitmq-plugins` command like so:

```
/usr/local/sbin/rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

You can add `/usr/local/sbin` to your path as described in the [official documentation "The Homebrew RabbitMQ Formula"](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-homebrew.html).

RabbitMQ not getting started by the `brew services` command could be related to [homebrew-core issue #17446](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/17446) where emptying `/usr/local/var/lib/rabbitmq` seem to fix the problem.